# Why the render buffer data is different produced by the same pipe line in OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl

The whole codes:

```
//two triangles color and position data
Vertex Verts[9] = { 
    { { 255,0,0,255 },{ 0.0f, 0.9f, 0.0f } },
    { { 0,255,0,255 },{ -0.9f, -0.9f, 0.0f } },
    { { 0,0,255,255 },{ 0.9f, -0.9f, 0.0f } } ,
    { { 255,255,255,255 },{ 0.0f, 0.8f, -0.2f } } ,
    { { 255,255,255,255 },{ -0.4f, 0.0f, -0.2f } } ,
    { { 255,255,255,255 },{ 0.4f, 0.0f, -0.2f } } ,
};
GLuint Program = 0;
GLuint vert;
GLuint vbo;
GLuint RendBuf[4], FrameBuf[2];
```

This is buffer set codes:

```
void Init()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vert);
    glBindVertexArray(vert);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Verts), Verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(Verts->color)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glUseProgram(Program);
```

I generate 4 render buffer,one depth buffer,three color buffer:

```
    glGenRenderbuffers(4, RendBuf);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, RendBuf[0]);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, 200, 200);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, RendBuf[1]);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 200, 200);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, RendBuf[2]);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, 200, 200);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, RendBuf[3]);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, 200, 200);
    //all buffer objects are bound to framebuffer object:FrameBuf[0]
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FrameBuf[0]);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuf[0]);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, RendBuf[0]);  
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_RENDERBUFFER, RendBuf[2]);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, RendBuf[1]);   
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_RENDERBUFFER, RendBuf[3]);
}
```

This is render code:

```
void Display()
{
    //draw in framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuf[0]);
    glViewport(0, 0, 200, 200);
    GLenum bufs[3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2};
    glDrawBuffers(3,bufs);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

change the background color of three triangles

```
    float Color[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, Color);
    float Color1[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 1, Color1);
    float Color2[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 2, Color2);
    glBindVertexArray(vert);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

copy the data from framebuffer to screen buffer

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuf[0]);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, 400, 400);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 200, 200, 0, 0, 200, 200, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 200, 200, 200, 0, 400, 200,GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 200, 200, 0, 200, 200, 400,GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

the vertex shader and fragment shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vColor;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 vPos;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vPos;
    color = vColor;
}

layout(location = 0) out vec4 fColor;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 fColor2;
void main()
{
    fColor = color;
    fColor2 = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

The first triangle is correct,the second is a blue triangle on yellow background,the third one is just light blue background.

Comment: Please add your shaders.

Comment: I have added the shaders at the end of the question,thanks for help!

Comment: I think the problem comes from the function glDrawBuffers(),the fragment shader should write same data into render buffer GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,but result doesn't follow this way.

Comment: Also what is the vertex data for the last triangle?

Comment: The first section is data code

Comment: The first section has two triangles and you are drawing three.

Comment: Your shaders write only to one output, which most likely ends up as color index 0, the outher two outputs are just undefined value, as per the spec

Comment: I tried to write data in three render buffers,data in the first one is correct,position data in the second is correct ,but color data isn't, and there is no data in third one.So I guess though using glDrawBuffers(3,buffers), there must be some limits.

Comment: I thought the codes are too long,so just casted some parts ,now I pasted all the codes ,sorry for the unclear question.